# Realm database synchronization over Dropbox

Tags: realm

I'm currently testing a setup of database synchronization over Dropbox with Realm for a macOS app but I have some issues with it.

The reason for why I'm trying this in the first place is because if I use the `Realm Browser` or the `Realm Studio` app to change some data in my database, my app is notified about the changes even when running and it reloads the data on screen perfectly so, in theory, a setup like this (synchronization over Dropbox or iCloud Drive) should work.

The problem is that when I'm running my app on 2 different devices when I'm doing a change in one of the apps the data is not persisted on disk after the write transaction happens so my other app does not know about the change and it doesn't reload the data so basically the "real-time" synchronization is not working.

So, would such a setup work, given the fact that using the `Realm Browser` and `Realm Studio` apps prove that it should work?

Comment: That will only work if the dropbox synchronization of modified Realm file occurs when Realm is closed on every thread.

Comment: Why don't you set up a Realm Object Server and use a synchronised Realm?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Synchronization is not part of the initial release, but if the method using Dropbox would have worked out of the box then we would have instructed our users on how to use it. We are considering Realm Object Server for when we launch the iOS version because only then our users will truly need synchronizing their data.

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce for your suggestion! Unfortunately, this would mean to change a big part of the codebase because I wrote a data manager around a single instance of the Realm and everything is tied to that instance, Realm notifications, CRUD operations, everything.

Comment: @DávidPásztor because ROS DEV edition is being sunset and the cloud is not cheap assuming linear price scale and the self-hosted costs are unknown (custom?) at this time ~ although this might change?

Comment: @arturgrigor I'm not joking though. If an open Realm which is memory-mapped is overwritten, then you'll be having invalid reads and crashes all over the place. It is safe to replace a Realm file with a new Realm file only if it is not open (aka closed). The Realm Browser / Realm Studio works with Realm's own tech, so it's a bit different than manually hacking something with Dropbox.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yeah, I know, but that's why I wrote this question here. I'm hoping to get an answer from someone inside the Realm project because ultimately I can dig into their source code and figure things out, but me not being part of the team means that I don't know the roadmap and things can change.